# Why am I getting the return value of None and what does it mean?

Tags: python, gaussian

I do no understand very well, the result: "none".  I am trying to start elimination (Gauss) code, but I receive the result: "None".

```
from numpy import *
a= array([[1,0],[0,2]])
b= array([1,4])

def gauss(a,b):
    n=len(b)

    k=0
    while k in range (0, n-1):
        i=k+1
        while i in range ((k+1),(n)):
            a[i,k]=a[i,k]/a[k,k]
            j=k+1
            while j in range ((k+1),(n)):
                a[i,j]=a[i,j]-a[i,k]*a[i,k]
                j=j+1
            b[i]=b[i]-a[i,k]*b[k]
            i=i+1
        k=k+1
        return a
        return b

 print gauss(a,b)
```

Comment: What are `a` and `b`? What is the test input... I assume this is Gaussian elliminiation so I expect some matrices?

Comment: you are not giving your function any actual values to calculate. When you call `gauss(a,b)` in the last line, you don't have any place where the numerical values of `a` and `b` are defined...

Comment: You are not returning a value from your function

Comment: Unrelated to your question about return values, but all of your `while` loops should probably be `for` loops instead (which will let you get rid of the initializers and manual incrementing lines). `while k in range(0, n-1)` is very unidiomatic, even if it is legal (if you really did want it, you'd probably use `while 0 <= k < n-1` instead). There are probably also numpy-specific ways to improve things even more, but I'm not sure what they are. Almost anything with loops in it is sub-optimal when numpy is involved.

Answer (score 4):

By default, functions in Python return `None` if there is no `return` statement, or it does not return any value. In your case, you could add `return a, b` to the end of your function. The result will be that the `gauss(a, b)` will return a tuple `(a, b)` with newly computed values.

```
from numpy import *
a= array([[1,0],[0,2]])
b= array([1,4])

def gauss(a,b):
    n=len(b)

    k=0
    while k in range (0, n-1):
        i=k+1
        while i in range ((k+1),(n)):
            a[i,k]=a[i,k]/a[k,k]
            j=k+1
            while j in range ((k+1),(n)):
                a[i,j]=a[i,j]-a[i,k]*a[i,k]
                j=j+1
            b[i]=b[i]-a[i,k]*b[k]
            i=i+1
        k=k+1
    return a, b

print gauss(a,b)
```

Comment: Apologies.  I do define a and b before the code starts.  Also, I should add "return b" and "return a" at end of the loop? When I did, I have the original matrix. No change.

Comment: Thank you, kroolik.  My code must be incorrect, as my matrix does not have changed values.